# numpy histogram stop producing bins that have no values in it

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have an array that numpy.histogram binning no values into some bins, when I specified bins=5. I would like the values to be binned so that no bin is left empty.

How can I achieve this?[image]

Comment: please share your data

Comment: @Goku  [1, 0.4537, 0.7037, 0.75,1,1,0.75,1,0.4537,1,0.4537,1,1,0.4537,1] is my array

Answer (score 1):

Your data only has 4 unique values, but you are asking for 5 bins, so it is forced to have some empty bins. If you set the number of bins to 4 you get 4 non-empty bins.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1, 0.4537, 0.7037, 0.75,1,1,0.75,1,0.4537,1,0.4537,1,1,0.4537,1])
counts,bins = np.histogram(data,bins=4)
```

This code gives non-empty bins.